# Bootstrap Modal pass input parameter to controller without closing modal

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I have a Modal with 2 Tabs and I have an input on one of them. I need to pass the value of that input to the controller after clicking the search button. After that, the modal should stay. How can i pass the parameter to the controller without closing the modal?

```
<div class="modal-body">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchKuerzel", "Home"))
    {
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="USZ-Kürzel" id="MyParameter" aria-label="USZ-Kürzel" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Mitarbeiter suchen</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    }    
</div>
```

Comment: you can use javascript `document.getElementById('MyParameter').value = 'Test'`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use javascript like @3xGuy has said or use jquery such as below:

```
$('#MyParameter').val();
```

to get the value and then use ajax to send information to the controller. From here can do whatever you want in the controller and just return Json such as below from the controller.

```
return Json(new {success = //true or false or whatever});
```

EDIT:

Once you have done what you want in the controller, you can return the value like I have returned the variable 'success' in the code above. In the result section of the ajax request you can get the data from the controller such as this:

```
//the rest of the ajax request
success: function(result)
{
     //Change the value of  html element to success in this case
     $('#//id of the element').text(result.success)
}
```

EDIT 2:

To return two Json strings do as above but add another return such as:

```
return Json(new {string1 = //whatever, string2 = //whatever});
```

And in the ajax access them like:

```
success:function(result)
{
    var return1= result.string1;
    var return12 = result.string2;

}
```

Comment: So ive managed to pass the parameter now just using the submit button and i get it in the controller. Only issue is I have that after the controller action is done, the modal shouldnt close. In fact, the modal should display the parameter again if it gets found in the json file (searching for that parameter in json through controller)

Comment: My point is the controller should "make something appear" in the modal after searching through the json file. Not return a new page or view. Just keeping the modal open. Is that even possible?

Comment: @MischaMorf You can do this using the process described above.

Comment: Worked great, thanks. Any idea on how to return 2 json strings and accessing them seperatly in the ajax?

Comment: @MischaMorf Editted answer to show how to get two strings. If you have found thai helpful and has answered the question, please feel free to mark as correct answer to help others.